# Memory management bsod during Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I have installed a fresh copy of Windows 7 on a brand new Asus K556UQ laptop,  with an i7 6500 processor,  12gb of ram and a 256GB ssd. The computer came with no operating system.  Due to driver incompatibility,  I had to install windows 10. However,  both flash drive and in media tool app upgrade failed.  More specifically,  the USB installation gave a memory management bsod and the application only an '' installation failed" message.  I have run the windows memory diagnostics and the sec scan utility and no problems were detected. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Asus E502S series notebook, I solved problem by using GPT schema instead of MBR while creating bootable pendrive (with Rufus).

It took me hours to get this, hope this post will help others.

Comment: Would be nice to know why/where exactly this helps. Memory management and partition type/firmware type (doesn't windows only do UEFI + GPT and bios/mbr?) don't feel like they're related.